# C# how to stop a program and its task completely

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am making a WPF Application with .NET Framework 2.0 and currently I am having trouble stopping the program, I try to do it like this

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Interrupt();
Application.ExitThread();
Application.Exit();
```

but after this code executes, I check the task manager, and there I see that my program is still running and do not have intentions of stopping any time soon...

How do I stop it completely?

Comment: You can try `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using :

```
Environment.Exit(0)
```

It will end all processes from all threads.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these:

// Graceful

Application.Current.Shutdown();

// Harsh out

Environment.Exit(0);

Answer (score -1):

How about `Response.End();` 
Not sure if this is what you are looking for